# Laravel Auth::basic() without user database

Tags: authentication, laravel, http-authentication

I'm wondering if the Auth::basic() function also works without database. I have searched the internet and found a similar question on stackoverflow but it has never been answered.

Thanks in advance,

Sjors

Comment: How would you store the usernames and passwords then?

Comment: @Jerodev Config file in combination with a sensitive data file for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you have to create a custom User Provider:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\User as UserContract;

class FileUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    /// Implement all UserProviderInterface (contract) methods

}
```

Then you just need to extend Auth with your own provider

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;

Auth::extend('file', function()
{
    return new Guard(
        new FileUserProvider(),
        App::make('session.store')
    );
});
```

Comment: Hmm not exactly what I mean. I don't need the auth driver, I just only need the HTTP Authentication once for a particuler page. I thought that Laravel could be used for this but I guess I'm wrong :P